# Erdas Er Mapper: Annotation vector layer to Shapefile

Tags: shapefile, erdas-imagine, er-mapper

I mapped some lines on Er Mapper 2014 with the Annotation tool (`Add vector layer > Annotation/Map composition`), so these lines are georeferenced and they got a specific width and colour.

I saved these lines in .erv format (actually, er mapper vector format).
And now, I would like to open them with QGis as Shapefile so I used the export tool to export the annotation map into a shapefile : `Utilities > Export Vector and GIS formats > ESRI Shape File > export`

But when I do that, I lost the colors and width of each lines (actually, the color mean a group of line and the width a subgroup of each color). The information is not stored on the shapefile (because it's a shapefile, so no problem here) but I wanted that the conversion stored an id for each color and same for each size.

Is that possible to do something like that ?

I also convert the Annotation layer to an autocad file and then, convert it into Google Earth file, the color is stored but not the size. Do you know how to stored the size while converting an Annotation layer to an autocad file then a KMZ file ? On kmz file, I should be able to read color and size of each lines and so, a python script will do the job to classify all the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Er Ermapper Vector files can be reads with texteditor. The color, the size and coordinates of each points composing each polylines (1 polylines = 1 line)  is noted on files and can be easily readable with texteditor.

A python script can do this conversion : read the Er Mapper Vector file and keep the color and size of polyline + coordinates to add them on a shapefile.